# How to use Angular2 unit-test Service to wait for an Observable function returns

Tags: angular, unit-testing

```
it('should push data into the array bank and get the array to count total length', async () =>  {
        const data = ... ;
        service.addData(data);

        await service.getData()
            .subscribe((data) => {
                console.log(data.length); <--- this never gets fired
                expect(data.length).toBe(5);
            });

    });
```

The problem is the test will fire the subscribe method and it never gets the correct data length. How can I tell jasmine to wait for the data to return and then do those checks?

Current, this test will pass all the time although I knew that `data.length` is not `5`.

```
public getData(): Observable<IData> {
    return this.data;
}
```

Comment: please post service.getDate() implementation

Comment: @TomaszKula sorry missed that out. updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

assuming service.data = Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5]);

```
it('should ...' , () =>  {
  let result = null;

  service.getData().subscribe(data => result = data);

  expect(result.length).toBe(5);
});
```

If you do not stub out service.data with of([....]), you must put the subscription block before invoking service.getData().

Comment: Glad I could help. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for your help!